# Client Side Validation with ASP.NET MVC 2 using SPARK view engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, client-side-validation, spark-view-engine

Is there a way to use Client Side Validation with the SPARK view engine?

I have the following SPARK view:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/content/script/shared/MicrosoftAjax.js?${ApplicationStartTime}"></script>      
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/content/script/shared/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js?${ApplicationStartTime}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/content/script/shared/jquery.validate.min.js?${ApplicationStartTime}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/content/script/shared/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js?${ApplicationStartTime}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/content/script/shared/MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js?${ApplicationStartTime}"></script>


<viewdata model="Business.Models.Development.Dtos.DonationFormDto" />

#Html.EnableClientValidation();

<form id="form" action="~/development/donate.mvc" method="post">

<label>
  *First Name
</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="model.FirstName" Id="FirstName" value="${Model.FirstName}"/> ${Html.ValidationMessage("model.FirstName")}
<br/>

</form>
```

Server-side validation works fine, but client-side validation doesn't.

I can make it work by using ASP.NET Helpers and form syntax like so:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Donate", FormMethod.Post, new {id = "form", action="donate.mvc" }))
{  
    <%=Html.LabelFor( model => model.FirstName) %><br/>
    <%=Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName)%>
    <%=Html.ValidationMessageFor( model => model.FirstName) %><br/>
}
```

But then my model doesn't bind correctly and sever-side validation fails on submit.

Any suggestions? Is abandoning SPARK and creating a classic strongly-typed view the only option?

Comment: m stuck with a similar issue now, did u find a solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

@KarlBear, why did you use "<%=" instead of "${...}" or "!{...}" in spark ?

```
${Html.LabelFor( model => model.FirstName)}<br/>
${Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName)}
${Html.ValidationMessageFor( model => model.FirstName)]<br/>
```

Comment: The MVC2 client-side validation seems to require the ASP.NET Helper syntax, so I used it instead of the regular SPARK syntax.  With SPARK syntax I couldn't get built-in client-side validation working.  I hear MVC3 has better built-in client-side validation that may work with SPARK, but I haven't looked into it yet.